# Reset xmodmap and setxkbmap to defaults

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I played around with xmodmap and setxkbmap on various occasions, for example to make an Apple keyboard work.

Now I cannot switch between input types anymore.

```
setxkbmap -v
```

returns

```
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete+numpad(mac)
compat:     complete+ledscroll(group_lock)
symbols:    macintosh_vndr/apple(alukbd)+macintosh_vndr/us(dvorak-alt-intl)+gb:2+inet(evdev)+group(alt_shift_toggle)+level3(ralt_switch)
geometry:   macintosh(applealu_iso)
Error loading new keyboard description
```

Some things are wrong here, I am currently not using an apple keyboard. How can I remove all custom modification I have made?